# Rails, Devise can't update my new fields like username

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I added :login, :username fields on the users table.
sign up and login work perfectly.
I changed devise.rb to authenticate :login instead of :email so that users can login with their own unique login id.

However, updating email and username fields on edit.html do not actually insert the record into my MySQL2 db.

I don't find any errors on console.
Although the parameters are successfully delivered, but its record was just not inserted.

Here is my [**gist address**](https://gist.github.com/geekerati/9464915).

Comment: Are those params permitted? Check `attr_accessible` in model (Rails 3) or `params.require(:user).permit` in controller (Rails 4).

Comment: I just added my gist files

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need to `update` the devise model with the newly added attributes, you need to permit them explicitly(Strong Parameters in Rails 4).
For example :

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :username ## add the attributes you want to permit
  end
end
```

Refer to [Devise documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters) on handling strong parameters.

Comment: OMG. YOU JUST FIXED MY PROBLEMS. THANK YOU ! I should have used :account_update in the 'for' method argument.